# Masonry with static contents and load more button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a Testimonials page that is used with Masonry plugin. I will have a lot of Testimonials but it will only show 4 when the page load and the rest will be hidden, there will be a load more button below.

I have achieve what I want but there is 1 issue.

The load more button is showing at the bottom of the last testimonial which is what I want but, there is a big gap from the displayed testimonials to the load more button. The reason is because masonry has set my wrapper with a height that includes all my testimonials including the hidden ones.

Is there any way that I do so that my load more button will display directly below the displayed testimonials?

Here is my code in [codepen](http://codepen.io/Dr3am3rz/pen/amdAoE).

```
<div class="testimonials">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="testi-wrapper">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Menaka Chandrashekhar, 32</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>I got my bee-utiful Alex Monroe bumble bee necklace from Annielka's Pop up shop at the MAAD market in the Red dot museum.</p>
                            <p>My hubby gifted me this neck piece for our third anniversary, a few weeks after I had been eyeing the fabulous jewellery on Annielka's website. The detailing of the bee pendant is simply exquisite..worthy of all the praise I've been getting about it :)</p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Digital Designer  |  Queensland, Australia</p>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Kirsten De Bruyn, 33</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>Bought my first 3 pieces at Annielka 2 weeks ago. Two massive rings and a very nice gold necklace. The pieces that Annielka sells are very different from what I have been able to find in Singapore. I personally like the bigger the better, but she also offers many other styles. The owner knows her stuff, and she advised me on the materials used in the pieces I was interested in so I knew what I was paying for. Very happy with my purchases and hope Annielka is here to stay. </p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Director pricing, capacity and contracting Europe and global  |  Amsterdam, Holland</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Menaka Chandrashekhar, 32</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>I got my bee-utiful Alex Monroe bumble bee necklace from Annielka's Pop up shop at the MAAD market in the Red dot museum.</p>
                            <p>My hubby gifted me this neck piece for our third anniversary, a few weeks after I had been eyeing the fabulous jewellery on Annielka's website. The detailing of the bee pendant is simply exquisite..worthy of all the praise I've been getting about it :)</p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Digital Designer  |  Queensland, Australia</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Kirsten De Bruyn, 33</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>Bought my first 3 pieces at Annielka 2 weeks ago. Two massive rings and a very nice gold necklace. The pieces that Annielka sells are very different from what I have been able to find in Singapore. I personally like the bigger the better, but she also offers many other styles. The owner knows her stuff, and she advised me on the materials used in the pieces I was interested in so I knew what I was paying for. Very happy with my purchases and hope Annielka is here to stay. </p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Director pricing, capacity and contracting Europe and global  |  Amsterdam, Holland</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Menaka Chandrashekhar, 32</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>I got my bee-utiful Alex Monroe bumble bee necklace from Annielka's Pop up shop at the MAAD market in the Red dot museum.</p>
                            <p>My hubby gifted me this neck piece for our third anniversary, a few weeks after I had been eyeing the fabulous jewellery on Annielka's website. The detailing of the bee pendant is simply exquisite..worthy of all the praise I've been getting about it :)</p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Digital Designer  |  Queensland, Australia</p>
                    </div>
                </div>



                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Kirsten De Bruyn, 33</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>Bought my first 3 pieces at Annielka 2 weeks ago. Two massive rings and a very nice gold necklace. The pieces that Annielka sells are very different from what I have been able to find in Singapore. I personally like the bigger the better, but she also offers many other styles. The owner knows her stuff, and she advised me on the materials used in the pieces I was interested in so I knew what I was paying for. Very happy with my purchases and hope Annielka is here to stay. </p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Director pricing, capacity and contracting Europe and global  |  Amsterdam, Holland</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Menaka Chandrashekhar, 32</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>I got my bee-utiful Alex Monroe bumble bee necklace from Annielka's Pop up shop at the MAAD market in the Red dot museum.</p>
                            <p>My hubby gifted me this neck piece for our third anniversary, a few weeks after I had been eyeing the fabulous jewellery on Annielka's website. The detailing of the bee pendant is simply exquisite..worthy of all the praise I've been getting about it :)</p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Digital Designer  |  Queensland, Australia</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 grid-item">
                    <div class="testi-img"><img src="http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                    <div class="testi-text">
                        <p class="name">Kirsten De Bruyn, 33</p>
                        <div class="testi">
                            <p>Bought my first 3 pieces at Annielka 2 weeks ago. Two massive rings and a very nice gold necklace. The pieces that Annielka sells are very different from what I have been able to find in Singapore. I personally like the bigger the better, but she also offers many other styles. The owner knows her stuff, and she advised me on the materials used in the pieces I was interested in so I knew what I was paying for. Very happy with my purchases and hope Annielka is here to stay. </p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="location">Director pricing, capacity and contracting Europe and global  |  Amsterdam, Holland</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="load-more">
                <p><strong><em>Load More Thank You Notes</em></strong></p>
                <button class="btn-more">Show More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: I fork your pen and it looks fine. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/full/VKZOow/ https://i.imgur.com/pQanrEX.jpg

Comment: Hi Jacob! Thanks for your help! Hmm, what I want to do is to show only 4 testimonials when page is load, the rest will be hidden. Also, I am not sure why my jquery code for my button can only work with v1.8.3 jquery and not the v3.1.0.

Comment: does your hidden item has a specific css class? if so, why not just use `display:none` on it ?

Comment: if you hide it using `display:none`, then you probably need to re arrange the layout everytime load more is clicked. If i remember correctly, `$grid.masonry()` will rearrange the masonry layout with new items.

Comment: Hi Jacob, my hidden item has no css class. I have tried to use display none and I have used javascript to display the 1st 4 items but somehow it is not displaying any item. But still, it doesn't solve remove the big white space between the 1st 4 items and the load more button.

Comment: if it were me doing it, i would find a way to add class to the hidden item 1st. then use CSS (not javascript) to apply `display:none` on it. Your masonry initialization function should come after the hidden item is hidden, otherwise, the plugin would create space for the hidden item and create the gap that you would like to eliminate.

Comment: the layout can be 're-masonry' using `$grid.masonry()` for unlimited time. so i think you may  're-masonry' it everytime you add/remove/hide something.

Comment: OMG! I didn't even notice that! =.=" Thanks a lot for telling me to switch the initialization function! Alright, so I got that fixed, now I will need to explore on the $grid.masonary(). When you mentioned everytime I add/remove something, are you referring to when the load more button is clicked?

Comment: yes. everytime you add/remove a new item into the masonary layout, you should 're-masonary' it.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I have make changes and added the .masonry() in my button function but somehow it's not working. I have tried to add .masonry() after .slideDown(); as well as adding an additional line $('.testimonials .testi-wrapper').masonry(); but still can't get it to work.

Comment: my mistake. for  're-masonry' , please use `$grid.masonry('layout');`

Comment: a rough example  of what `$grid.masonry('layout');` do https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/xEkvNp?editors=0010

Comment: Hmm... That means I can't put 2 action into a single button click. Eg. unhide element then relayout in a single click. Am I right?

Comment: no. that's just an example to show you the different processes. you can put both together =] pls try for yourself

Comment: Hi Jacob, I have already tried though but it's not working. I have to click the button twice. The 1st click, it will slidedown showing the hidden content and the 2nd click will then re-layout.

Comment: i think the reason is that the 're-layout' happen when the 'slidedown' is not fully completed yet.

Comment: Hi Jacob! It's working already! Suddenly it just strike my mind. I should have put the .masonry in the slideDown() function inside of just extending it after the slideDown(). Thanks a lot for your help! =D How do I upvote you or your answer? LOL

Comment: so you need to find a way to trigger 're-layout' after 'slidedown' is completed.

Comment: oh good you found a way. i compiled my comments as answer and you mark it as correct ?/

Comment: Yeah! Suddenly I realized that it is possible to do slideDown(function(){}); while staring at it. Eureka! LOL Alright! Will do so once you are done. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solutions are found when OP and I chat in the comments. Anyway, these are the main points:

---

1. Timing of masonry initialization is important.

In the case above, the masonry is initialized before some of the content is hidden. Masonry plugin will set a fixed height to the containing div. Removing content after masonry initialization create an empty space at the bottom of the  masonry containing div.

2. the use of `$grid.masonry('layout');` (http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout-masonry)

`$grid.masonry('layout');` will re-layout the masonry. Every time content is added/removed/showed/hidden in masonry layout, it needs to be re-layout so that the new element can be position correctly. Example: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/full/xEkvNp/

3. timing of `$grid.masonry('layout');` is important

same reason as point 1. Do it after the 'showing/hiding/loading' is completed, or else the layout may go wrong.

4. generally, you can use `$grid.masonry('layout');` for an unlimited amount of time

---

That's all. Hope that this helps those who are using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! =D Btw, is there any way that I can contact you? Needa ask you something that is off track.

Comment: @Dr3am3rz you can contact me at jacobgoh101@gmail.com =]